# How to fix hang during shutdown of OSX Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, time-machine, performance, shutdown

My MacBook Pro Retina 15-inch Early 2013, running Sierra 10.12.6 has a long standing issue where everytime I reboot (for many months now), it hangs during shutdown with a spinning icon near end of shutdown process that remains stuck spinning even if I let it run overnight.  Upon forced power off and restart, I get the following report:

```
Anonymous UUID:       77844606-CC97-41AA-EDF6-B18C43EFEB66

Tue Aug 15 16:27:38 2017

*** Panic Report ***
Panic(CPU 2): NMIPI for spinlock acquisition timeout, spinlock: 0xffffff8024e67180, spinlock owner: 0xffffff804a484288, current_thread: 0xffffff804a484288, spinlock_owner_cpu: 0x2
RAX: 0x0000000bc38babab, RBX: 0xffffff804a484288, RCX: 0x0000000000000260, RDX: 0x0000000b00000000
RSP: 0xffffff82031bb870, RBP: 0xffffff82031bb8b0, RSI: 0xffffff804a484288, RDI: 0xffffff8024e67180
R8:  0xffffff80248084ec, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000000010, R11: 0x0000000000000010
R12: 0x0000000000000001, R13: 0xffffff804a484288, R14: 0x0000000bc38c178e, R15: 0xffffff8024e67180
RFL: 0x0000000000000097, RIP: 0xffffff80246f7942, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff82031bb710 : 0xffffff80247fd781 
0xffffff82031bb770 : 0xffffff802469a8bf 
0xffffff82031bb8b0 : 0xffffff80247f5683 
0xffffff82031bb8d0 : 0xffffff8024c62417 
0xffffff82031bbcf0 : 0xffffff80246fc81e 
0xffffff82031bbd90 : 0xffffff80248084ec 
0xffffff82031bbdd0 : 0xffffff8024807913 
0xffffff82031bbe40 : 0xffffff802480743d 
0xffffff82031bbf50 : 0xffffff802480628b 
0xffffff82031bbf70 : 0xffffff80247fd781 
0xffffff82031bbfd0 : 0xffffff802469a759 
0xffffff921157b990 : 0xffffff802473013f 
0xffffff921157b9e0 : 0xffffff8024b9e3b2 
0xffffff921157ba10 : 0xffffff8024b9895a 
0xffffff921157ba40 : 0xffffff802494926f 
0xffffff921157baa0 : 0xffffff80249546d3 
0xffffff921157bb10 : 0xffffff8024b5c340 
0xffffff921157bbe0 : 0xffffff8024b5bc35 
0xffffff921157bc70 : 0xffffff8024b5a700 
0xffffff921157bdb0 : 0xffffff8024b5cbc6 
0xffffff921157be00 : 0xffffff7fa53217c0 
0xffffff921157bf50 : 0xffffff7fa5321dee 
0xffffff921157bfb0 : 0xffffff80246978f7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.kec.pthread(1.0)[225C22A5-813D-3651-9C40-FDEEAB0D78E1]@0xffffff7fa531e000->0xffffff7fa532cfff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: logd

Mac OS version:
16G29

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: D3314D98-5D40-3CD8-98A4-F1DD46C20E03
Kernel slide:     0x0000000024400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8024600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8024500000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 14586799298
last loaded kext at 10586560062: com.intel.kext.intelhaxm   1.1.1 (addr 0xffffff7fa7e57000, size 126976)
loaded kexts:
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    1.1.1
com.intel.driver.EnergyDriver   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.17
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    131
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.14.49
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   279.48
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   279.48
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   279.48
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.5f1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.GeForce   10.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.9.20
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.14.49
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.2.5
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    10.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   5.0.5f1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   252
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  252
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 252
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  366.70.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.26
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  295.20.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.2.10
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1150.12.1a1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  326.60.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 219.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   172
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   219.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 279.48
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.1.7
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   159.9
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 279.48
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 279.48
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.15
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   516.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.14.49
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    311.14
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.14.49
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    515.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   5.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   394.50.1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 5.0.5f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   5.0.5f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.5f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.5f1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 258
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.5.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.5.7
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 444.50.16
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff8024c62417): "Spinlock acquisition timed out: lock=0xffffff8024e67180, lock owner thread=0xffffff804a484288, current_thread: 0xffffff8049e216f8, lock owner active on CPU 0x2, current owner: 0xffffff804a484288"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3789.70.16/osfmk/i386/locks_i386.c:427
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff82031da850 : 0xffffff80246e953c 
0xffffff82031da8d0 : 0xffffff8024c62417 
0xffffff82031dacf0 : 0xffffff80246fc81e 
0xffffff82031dad90 : 0xffffff80248084ec 
0xffffff82031dadd0 : 0xffffff8024807913 
0xffffff82031dae40 : 0xffffff802480743d 
0xffffff82031daf50 : 0xffffff802480628b 
0xffffff82031daf70 : 0xffffff80247fd781 
0xffffff82031dafd0 : 0xffffff802469a759 
0xffffff820cb3b490 : 0xffffff7fa678f1bb 
0xffffff820cb3b4c0 : 0xffffff7fa679454c 
0xffffff820cb3b530 : 0xffffff7fa6610112 
0xffffff820cb3b590 : 0xffffff7fa66199df 
0xffffff820cb3b610 : 0xffffff7fa661bb80 
0xffffff820cb3b760 : 0xffffff7fa661a099 
0xffffff820cb3b7a0 : 0xffffff7fa679682d 
0xffffff820cb3b7f0 : 0xffffff7fa664cce1 
0xffffff820cb3b900 : 0xffffff7fa664c6f6 
0xffffff820cb3b940 : 0xffffff7fa6895ece 
0xffffff820cb3b990 : 0xffffff7fa65a7e75 
0xffffff820cb3b9e0 : 0xffffff7fa6505d09 
0xffffff820cb3ba00 : 0xffffff7fa6506259 
0xffffff820cb3ba70 : 0xffffff7fa5a569d4 
0xffffff820cb3baa0 : 0xffffff8024cbd76a 
0xffffff820cb3bb10 : 0xffffff7fa5a56a3b 
0xffffff820cb3bb60 : 0xffffff7fa6504891 
0xffffff820cb3bba0 : 0xffffff802497e099 
0xffffff820cb3bbf0 : 0xffffff8024972cbd 
0xffffff820cb3bcc0 : 0xffffff8024970e06 
0xffffff820cb3bda0 : 0xffffff802497697f 
0xffffff820cb3bdd0 : 0xffffff8024ba2460 
0xffffff820cb3be10 : 0xffffff8024b51c2b 
0xffffff820cb3be40 : 0xffffff8024b9c733 
0xffffff820cb3bf50 : 0xffffff8024c240f5 
0xffffff820cb3bfb0 : 0xffffff802469ad96 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.2)[6326DB88-5330-3F0C-91F6-D478AB5E7503]@0xffffff7fa5a4e000->0xffffff7fa5a7afff
         com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family(1200.12.2)[1C010821-6A22-3C8C-B396-409023E8A540]@0xffffff7fa649c000->0xffffff7fa6581fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.corecapture(1.0.4)[C269B594-3CE8-3AC8-AC81-ADDCC1C9074A]@0xffffff7fa646a000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[E54425FE-971A-38E2-8F27-82A1B7A3479D]@0xffffff7fa52d8000
            dependency: com.apple.kec.corecrypto(1.0)[E3701C61-A548-3181-9F3E-C90DF8327185]@0xffffff7fa522f000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.2)[6326DB88-5330-3F0C-91F6-D478AB5E7503]@0xffffff7fa5a4e000
         com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360(1150.12.1a1)[BB3626FA-A579-348F-AF69-3249DAC7949D]@0xffffff7fa658c000->0xffffff7fa6d48fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.corecapture(1.0.4)[C269B594-3CE8-3AC8-AC81-ADDCC1C9074A]@0xffffff7fa646a000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient(1.0.1b8)[EE4CC064-65B6-3978-9393-C71C74D5BEAA]@0xffffff7fa617a000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family(1200.12.2)[1C010821-6A22-3C8C-B396-409023E8A540]@0xffffff7fa649c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[3E00E7D2-E569-341D-9BE0-34D5DE491825]@0xffffff7fa4f48000
            dependency: com


Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B12, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.7 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.130.1a1)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.5f1, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD512E, 500.28 GB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

I had the Genius store reinstall my operating system and I recovered my drive from timemachine backup, but problem still remains on every shutdown.

---

I patched HAXM to the latest version.  After doing that, booting in `safe mode` results in a successful shutdown. However, shutting down with `sudo shutdown -h now` locks up just like a normal shutdown.

---

I tried a new user with Admin privileges and it got the same hang.  I even tried shutdown from login screen after boot and never having logged in and it also hangs.

---

Here are the non-Apple signed extensions:

- ACS6x: Version: 3.1.8
- ATTOCelerityFC8: Version: 2.5.6
- ATTOExpressSASHBA2: Version: 2.4.6
- ATTOExpressSASRAID2: Version: 3.7.1
- ArcMSR: Version: 1.3.7
- BJUSBLoad: Version: 10.69.0
- BJUSBMP: Version: 2.9.0 (The oldest one, last modified: 11/21/10)
- CalDigitHDProDrv: Version: 2.1.2
- Dropbox: Version: 1.8.1
- EnergyDriver: Version: 2.0
- HighPointIOP: Version: 4.3.2
- HighPointRR: Version: 4.3.3
- JMicronATA: Version: 1.1.6 (The second oldest, last modified: 5/22/12)
- ProlificUsbSerial: Version: 1.6.0
- PromiseSTEX: Version: 5.2.10
- SoftRAID: Version: 5.5.2
- SophosFileProtection: Version: 9.6.51
- SophosWebProtection: Version: 9.6.50
- fuse4x: Version: 0.9.2
- heimdall: Version: 6.0

Comment: could you check your CPU usage next time before shutdown ?

Comment: did you ever do hardware test, specific the memory test ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 The genius bar ran their hardware test before reinstalling OS.  CPU appears normal before I begin shutdown, were you asking during?  During shutdown, the Activity Monitor will be quit, so once that happens not sure if I can monitor CPU any further.

Comment: the reason I was asking about CPU is that your Panic report says it is a problem with CPU !

Comment: Does the problem exist when you boot into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262)?  Also try doing a clean install (on a USB drive would be fine as it's just for testing).

Comment: That that means there is *something* (possibly in your profile) is getting loaded that is hanging the system.  To rule that out, create a new user with admin rights and see if the problem exists there.  If it doesn't, it's something custom to your account, if the problem persists, it's system wide.

Comment: @Allan Question is updated.  New admin user fails too, even never login fails to shutdown.

Comment: Now we know it's system wide.  There's two ways to attack this - 1)  get an inventory of everything you have installed and see if we can find an issue or 2) do a clean install and migrate your data.   I would go with option 2 personally so I can be sure everything is clean going forward.  Make sure you do a Time Machine backup before proceeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Allan, I decided to do a complete reinstall of the operating system and migrate my data back to it. This is what ultimately worked for me.  I backed up my machine and made an appointment at the genius bar.  I went to the genius store for my appointment and had them to reinstall the operating system and after reinstall I was able to use time machine to restore my data.  It took about an hour.  Since then, the machine shuts down properly.

---

Updating to Mac OS X High Sierra fixed the problem.  Computer now reboots properly.